# Filtering Array of Vars in Ansible

Tags: arrays, nginx, server, ansible

Currently we have a *huge* file that contains all of our nginx configs for each site we work on. The file has about 150 lines or so of sites like this:

```
- { nginx_tempalte: 'site.conf.tpl', domain: 'example.com', server: 'ServerA', enabled: true, conf_name: 'example_site'  }
```

Our playbook loops through each var 2 times. Once for getting it into `sites-enabled` and another for the symlink. This takes about 5 minutes each loop which isn't ideal.

I tried setting up a nested loop that takes in a registered variabled that has all the config names from the sites-available and checks them against the given var from earlier. However this seems like more of the same approach.

I would love some help filtering down these files.

Comment: Could you please send an example of how are you getting the data? Do you have the whole dict in a var?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how are you getting the dict. If it is a variable, you can have:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  # with predefined vars
  vars:

    nginx: { nginx_tempalte: 'site.conf.tpl', domain: 'example.com', server: 'ServerA', enabled: true, conf_name: 'example_site'  }

  tasks:

    - name: Fact
      set_fact:
        domain: "{{ nginx['domain'] }}"
        server: "{{ nginx['server'] }}"

    - name: Print Domain
      debug:
        var: domain

    - name: Print Server
      debug:
        var: server
```

And you will have both values at the same time:

```
PLAY [Test] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Fact] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print Domain] ************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "domain": "example.com"
}

TASK [Print Server] ************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "server": "ServerA"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```